# Javascript - Form post parameters lost after user logs in

Tags: javascript, forms

I am dynamically creating a form and doing a submit which redirects the user to another domain(lets say redirecting to mangoes.com from apples.com) using javascript.

```
        var demFrm = document.createElement('form');
        document.body.appendChild(demFrm);
        demFrm.setAttribute("action", "https://mangoes.com");
        demFrm.setAttribute("name", "demo");
        var hiddenInput =  document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenInput.setAttribute("name", "Quantity");
        hiddenInput.setAttribute("value", "3");
        demFrm.appendChild(hiddenInput);
        demFrm.setAttribute("method", "post");
        demFrm.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        demFrm.submit();
```

If the user is already logged in the mangoes.com website, the form parameters are still present. But if user has to login to the website, after login, the form post parameter is lost. How do I still have that "Quantity" parameter after the user has finished login